# Spyder's Variable explorer is inconsistent when it lists variables

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have just installed the latest Anaconda package available on Anaconda website. I have now Spyder 2.3.7 running with Python 3.5. Operating system is OSX El Capitan 10.11 running on a newly purchased iMac. I also have a 3 year old MacBook Air running Spyder 2.3.5.2 with Python 3.4.3-2.

On the new iMac, I run a python file which creates some large dict objects. However, only one of these dict objects show up in the Variable explorer. The others don't. When I run the same python file on my old MacBook Air, all the dict objects show up in Variable explorer. Can anyone help please? I searched for an answer online but can not find anything. Thank you.

Comment: how are you creating the dict objects? what does the code look like? is it using files?

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't fit here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Unless you can show us some associated code ? Then edit question.

Comment: I use pickle.load to load up some rather large dataframes to memory. I then convert them to lists and use a for loop to create the dictionary objects. Does this answer your question? Thank you.

Comment: Just for the record, this was reported here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2815 and it'll be solved in Spyder 2.3.8.